# Can we ask about software problems we have while recording?

Tags: discussion

I know that there have numerous discussions on meta concerning questions about music software, but I haven't been that active lately, so I'm sure what is on topic and what is not.

If I'm trying to record my guitar using software X and I have the Y problem, can I ask about it here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes! Questions about specific software are on-topic, it's software *recommendation* questions that are not.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with NReilingh for almost all, however [this one](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/29158/104) seems to be an example of a question which shouldn't fit here:

> How to lock out a Behringer x32 Mixer? [on hold]
>
> We have bought a Behringer x32 Mixer and there is a opportunity on the display to lock down the Mixer. We have locked down, but we don't know how to lock out it. If we switch off the all Mixer and turn on, the Mixer will lock out, but during a concert we can't switch off the Mixer. How can we lock out it?

As Wheat and Jörg pointed out, it is a simple "read the manual" question.

Comment: "Simple" and "read the manual" [does not necessarily mean off-topic](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/676/are-questions-about-electronic-music-equipment-on-topic).