# Is it on topic to ask about how to improve the recording of an acoustic piano?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I think this is almost on the same vein as [this meta question](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2081/can-we-ask-about-software-problems-we-have-while-recording), but I still wanted to make sure.

I tried to record myself trying out an upright piano at the piano store with a portable recording device. Initially, it sounded good enough. But after some thoughts, I'm thinking there might be techniques to improve the sampling while I'm playing.

I was wondering if it's on topic to post a sample of the recording, describe in what position the recording device was positioned, the settings of the device (microphone amplification for example), and ask about what can be done to improve the recording quality?

I'm thinking this might be opinion-based, too broad, or more of an "audio engineering" problem than about Music practice and theory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions about recording are on topic here - there's a [recording tag](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recording) with some questions in the same general area. A question along the lines of "how to get the best results when recording an upright piano with a portable recorder" seems reasonable, though you might want to indicate what your personal priorities are when it comes to judging what good results would be.

There's also a [recording tag](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recording) on the sound design SE, and they specifically state 'field recording' to be one of their [on-topic areas](https://sound.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so you could consider that site too.

Answer (score 4):

Even if it's on topic, you should note that there are already several questions here on recording pianos. If you do ask one it's quite likely to be a duplicate. It might be a good idea to read all the relevant questions, both here and on Sound Design SE, before asking.

Comment: Seems like it mostly comes down to mic positioning (although in my case, I also had the problem of setting the level of recording too high, because of which it was recording every single footsteps in the room).

Comment: @Clockwork The solution to that is to avoid the footsteps and not turn the recording level down.